# 単一のstringやオブジェクトを標準出力に出力するには？

Tags: f#

つまりC#で言うところの

```cs
var str = "example;
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

のようなことをしたいのですが、`printfn` を使った場合、第一引数は常に書式文字列として扱われてしまうため、次のコードはエラーになります。

```
let str = "example"
printfn str
printfn DateTime.Now
```

> error FS0001: 型 'string' は型 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>' と互換性がありません

このエラー自体は合点がいきますし、次のように書くのが正しいでしょう。

```
printfn "%s" str
printfn "%O" DateTime.Now
```

ただ、これだけのために書式文字列を指定するのは無駄な処理をしているように見えます。

`Console.WriteLine(string)` や `Console.WriteLine(object)` のように、単一の文字列やオブジェクトの出力に特化した関数はないのでしょうか？

---

```
Console.WriteLine str
Console.WriteLine DateTime.Now
```

と直接Consoleクラスのメソッドを呼び出すことはできますが、F#版の関数が用意されているならそれを使った方がいいのでは、と思った次第です。それとも上記メソッドを直接呼び出せばいいのでしょうか。

（標準関数のprintfとクラスライブラリのConsoleみたいな違いを感じているというか・・・）

Comment: `System.Console.WriteLine` はF#からでもそのまま使えますけどそういうことではないんですよね？

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `Console.WriteLine(string, object[])` のF#版が `printfn` だとすると、`Console.WriteLine(string)` のF#版も何か用意されているのかなと。`printfn` に標準関数のようなイメージを抱いているのですが、単にF#で扱いやすいバージョンが追加されてるだけなんですかね・・・？

Comment: 私は、`printf` シリーズはどっちかというとCの`printf`系のチェック強化版というようなイメージでいます(そしてこれをうまくF#で書くのは大変です)。 ソースで言うと`printf`系はcoreの部分に入っているのでそういう意味で標準関数と考えて良いと思います。単一の文字列の出力関数(例えばCでいう`puts`)については必要であれば簡単に自己定義の関数として作成できますので、あえて作る必要もなかったということじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: （私の記憶というのは結構古いので変更があったかもしれないですが）F#で文字列を標準出力へ出力する単純な関数は無かったように思います。(リテラルは `printfn "example"`で出力できます。)

Comment: ソース(最新ではないかも)は[ここ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18706)から 
`fsharp.zip`をダウンロードできます。

Comment: 個人的には`let puts (str:string) = stdout.WriteLine str` で十分かと。型チェックを行うのがダイレクト呼び出しと違うところ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[F#のPrintfモジュール](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.printf-module-%5Bfsharp%5D)は[OCamlのPrintfモジュール](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html)を基にしています。ですので`System.Console`はあまり意識されていません。例えば`CurrentCulture`を無視しますので

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture <- System.Globalization.CultureInfo "de"
System.Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}", 12.34)  // 12,34
printfn "%.2f" 12.34                       // 12.34
```

といった違いもあります。ですのでOCaml風フォーマッタと考えるべきかと思います。
（その割に`printfn`とか日和った関数があるんですよね…。）

Answer (score 1):

ざっと[Microsoft.FSharp.Core リファレンス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/microsoft.fsharp.core-namespace-%5bfsharp%5d) を眺めて見たのですが、相当するような関数は見当たらないようです。

[Getting Started...](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-visual-studio)を見ると、
つらっと文字列の表示で
`System.Console.WriteLine(aString)`
なんて例があるのでおそらくは文字列のみを標準出力に出力するF#の関数は用意されていないのだと思います。